# how to print a list of unique values?

Tags: r, unique

I have created an object of unique values:

```
obj <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
```

I would like to print it in the following message:

```
message("The zones are:", obj,"\n")
```

but the output all values are joint together:

```
#The zones are:ABCDE
```

I would like to have the values comma separated

I also tried `print(paste0("The zones are:", obj,"\n"))` but it gives even worse output

Comment: `message("The zones are:", toString(obj),"\n")`

Comment: message("The zones are : ", paste0(obj, collapse = ", "), "\n")

Answer (score 0):

We can use `toString` to create a single string that is comma separated

```
 message("The zones are:", toString(unique(obj)), "\n")
```